# How can I get around this Safari outline bug?

Tags: css, safari, outline

When using Safari, Setting an outline in CSS causes issues for selectable elements where the outline dynamically changes. Some of the outline gets left behind on previously selected elements:

```
.box {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
.box.selected {
  outline: 5px solid blue;
}
```

Here is a CodeSandbox that demonstrates the problem. In order to reproduce, it has to be run on Safari: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-shockley-luu3m?file=/src/App.js&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675

Has anyone experienced this issue and been able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

That’s how it works for the safari browser but you can try changing the style for .box from `outline` to `border`

```
.box {
  height: 75px;
  width: 100px;

  border: 2px solid black;

  margin: 0px 5px;
  background: red;
}

.box.selected {
  outline: 5px solid blue;
}
```